# listview hex math difficulty

Tags: c#, listview

I have a listview, in a row it shows a list of integers (more than 1500). Is there a way to hex minus 0x80000000 from each integer using for or foreach ?

I don't think this needs me to post any code, but if anyone needs anything related to this question, I'll be more than happy to edit the question and add the code.

Comment: Maybe you could mention in passing what language you happen to be using ?

Comment: OK - I've fixed the tags for you now - try to remember to tag with programming language next time you post a question

Comment: What do you mean with 'to hex minus 0x80000000' ?

Comment: Thanks **Paul**, and **MiMo**, imagine i have a column full of hex number, and i need a loop to go through all of those numbers and removes 0x80000000 from each hex number, i don't know how to write it :s
Thank you.

Comment: i don't know why but this is not working for me for some reason :s
`for (int j = 0; j < offsets.Count; j++)
                {
                    listView1.Items[j].SubItems[0] - 0x80000000;
                }`